# AJAX_CURL Bad Request 400

Tags: php, ajax, http, curl

I am using SMS API :

1. Through HTTP URL its working fine URL sample is:

http://testxyz.com?user=xyz&password=xyz&mob=xyz&sid=xyz&msg=xyz

2. Through CURL curl_init($url); Its also working fine

But when I am using AJAX and call the CURL 2nd option its showing me Bad Request 400

**AJAX Code**

var dataString = "mobile="+mobile+"&sentSMS="+sentSMS;

$.ajax({

```
       type: "POST",
        url: "getMessage.php",
        data: dataString,
        async:false,
        beforeSend: 
        function(){         
            $("#msg_result").html("Please wait.....");  
        },             
        success: function(msg){
            $("#msg_result").html("Sent...");
        },
```

});
    }

**getMessage.php**

$ch = curl_init("http://testxyz.com?user=xyz&password=xyz&mob=xyz&sid=xyz&msg=xyz");

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

Any suggestion please.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: If you show us the code...

Comment: @MatthewBrown just update ajax and curl code

Comment: return curl output on php page

Comment: @SunilPachlangia tried but same result.

Comment: Your URL sample has GET params, but your AJAX request has `type: "POST"`. Does that matter to your back-end?